Export a ollama custom model I created
I have just created an app that use a custom ollama model based on llama3 and for easy deployment i want to add except(or in replace) to my model file the actual "compiled" model, i saw that you can load a model from a bin file but i couldn't find a way to export my model out to a bin or to any format at all, i want to just add it to my github repo to make the setup for my project dont include the creation of the model in the user PC and naming it the same as mentioned in the code, im just a starter in ollama and maybe there isn't even a way to do it, but if someone know a way i would appreciate if you could help
I guess i searched the docs and google for a solution but couldn't find nothing.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
